# Remove separator if line break

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

## problem

How do I remove a bullet point `&bull;` when there is a line break? For example,

`abc • defg`

has the bullet point while

```
abc
defg
```

doesn't?
Here's what's happening:

```html
<textarea readonly cols="50" rows="5">big fat long line &bull; longer line haha whoopsie</textarea>
<textarea readonly cols="20" rows="5">big fat long line &bull; longer line haha whoopsie</textarea>
```

Comment: Your snippet shows a different scenario where the bullet point and a word are still on the first line and the following words on the second line. Are you saying you want the line break if there has to be one to be at the bullet point position?

Answer (score 2):

Although you show the bullets as being part of the text to achieve this in CSS you will need some structure to the text. In particular so the system knows to break at the bullet points not after any convenient word.

This snippet forms the text into an unordered list with each list item set as an inline-block but the 'normal' bullet point before such an item restored with a before pseudo element. The first bullet points on each line are overwritten by a before pseudo element on the ul element.

Try the snippet in full page and then gradually reduce the window size.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

ul:before {
  content: '\00a0 \2022 \000a0 ';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  color: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li:before {
  content: '\00a0 \2022 \000a0 ';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text of a different length</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wait, I tried it, but it didn't work, instead it showed half a bullet point before the text, and two bullet points (on different lines) in the middle

Comment: Sounds nasty! What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 94.0 on Fedora 35.

Comment: Hmm, I just can't make it go wrong but I've only got Windows 10 (Edge/Chrome and Firefox). Is it running the snippet direct from here that gives the problem?

Comment: no it works perfectly on the snippet but when i try to use it somewhere else (i replaced the `ul` with `nav` and `li` with `a`, maybe that's the problem?) it doesn't work very well. The text I'm using is "What's happening?" and "How to help". 
I actually already solved the problem using Javascript but if someone gives me a pure css solution, it would be way better.

Comment: Yes, you need some HTML structure that knows not to split things up when there has to be wrapping - that is something ul gives you, I wouldn't expect it to work on random elements.